# Spatial index on hive

Tags: hadoop, gis, hive, spatial, spatial-index

I am creating tables in hive for a spatialdatabase, I know there are special indexes for spatial data, which are R-tree. In hive create a spatial index is not possible (i think). I was thinking about trying to make a index of x, y (long, lat), continuous variables with decimals. I do not think that is the most efficient.

We are using esri libraries for spatial algebra, but in some cases the query performance is very poor.

[Esri gis tools for hadoop](http://esri.github.io/gis-tools-for-hadoop/)

I was thinking ....

Is it better to create an index for these two variables, or partition the table by a variable of type  xi = int(x/0.2) * 0.2, yi = int(y/0.2) * 0.2?

I think a table partition is more efficient, but the design is more complex queries, also I think that the partition does not support numeric variables with decimals

The most typical queries with bounding box will be a range of spatial data. Anyone know an efficient way to structure the data with hive for this kind of queries?

Is there a method to create and implentar an R-tree in hive? Can you partition a table with continuous values ​​with decimals (I've seen many examples and seems not)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean "partition a table with continuous values"?

Comment: You may also be interested in:  Randall T. Whitman, Michael B. Park, Sarah M. Ambrose, and Erik G. Hoel. 2014. Spatial indexing and analytics on Hadoop. In *Proceedings of the 22nd ACM SIGSPATIAL International Conference on Advances in Geographic Information Systems* (SIGSPATIAL '14). ACM, New York, NY, USA, 73-82. DOI=10.1145/2666310.2666387 http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2666310.2666387

Answer (score 0):

There are also k-dimensional tree for spatial data, it's should me much simpler to operate with.

Answer (score 0):

I've only seen examples of partitions with dates. A tyle 2012, 2013 .... etc. These are really discrete values. I do not know if you can define a partition with ranges for example: y in [40.1, 42.4), and x in [-4,0), another patition y in [42.4, 43), and x in [-4,0) .. . etc. Partitions do not have statics ranges, because there will be space areas which do not have much information. It's a way to make a Quadtree  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree , but associated with the partitions, without index. I think it would work as an spatial index, will works in hive, and maybe a elegant way.

This is my idea. I hope someone finds a way to make the partitions as well, and most importantly is that x and y are variables that determine the partition to check, or an elegant alternative

This is a example to make partitions

CREATE TABLE sales (
    sales_order_id  BIGINT,
    order_amount    FLOAT,
    order_date      STRING,
    due_date        STRING,
    customer_id     BIGINT
)
PARTITIONED BY (country STRING, year INT, month INT, day INT) ;